# List containers from other users?

Tags: container, podman

Is there a way to list all running podman containers on a machine, including those from other users?

Even if I log in as root, `podman ps -a` just lists all containers for the user, but I want to see all containers on the machine.

Comment: Have you got admin rights on the machine - i.e. can you  do ``sudo podman  ps -a``  [maybe that'll show everything?]

Comment: @MrR he/she says he/she has, and no, it won't.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no facility in podman itself to do that – it'd go against podman philosophy to have a central daemon to arbitrate creation of containers!

However, containers are still mostly fancy namespaces, so you can use the `lsns` ("list namespaces") tool get a list of all of them

```
lsns
```

Lots of namespaces! Let's restrict ourselves to these which are mount namespaces:

```
lsns -t mnt
```

much better!

Now, you can get the process ID of the process that *created* the namespace - and that would be podman!

```
lsns -t mnt -n -o PPID
```

Now let's put this all together:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
ppids=$(lsns -t mnt -n -o PPID)
uids=""
for ppid in ${ppids}; do
  uids="${uids}\n$(stat -c '%u' /proc/$ppid)"
done
uids=$(echo "$uids" | sort -u)
for uid in uids; do
  ## su(do) as that user: podman ps -a
done
```

Comment: Quote _An important note is that even if you can use rootless Podman with sudo or su on your system, it is not recommended._ from the Red Hat blog post [_Why can't I use sudo with rootless Podman?_](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/sudo-rootless-podman). Maybe the recommended way is `sudo machinectl shell username@ /bin/bash -c "podman ps -a"` ? Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131894/how-to-list-rootless-containers-of-all-the-users

Comment: hm, that su was to change to become some other user than root. Clearly, non-root users shouldn't be allowed to inspect other users' containers...

Comment: Yes, if the script is running as root you could use `machinectl shell username@ /bin/bash -c "podman ps -a"` . The Red Hat blog post recommends using `machinectl login` instead of `su` because `su` does not create a login session that is needed by Podman. I think in a script `machinectl shell` should be used instead (or the hackish workaround `ssh localhost ...`)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `systemd-run --uid=1000 --pty --wait --collect --service-type=exec /usr/bin/podman ps -a` because I learned that machinectl doesn't return the status code, which for `podman ps` is fine but other commands will be needed.

Comment: Another alternative: `systemd-run --machine=1000@ --quiet --user --collect --pipe --wait --collect podman ps -a`

Comment: Wrote a modified version of this for Bash in Ubuntu https://gist.github.com/caffeineaddiction/92c744609fc65199bb66042e4aaeecfc future me might find this useful.